# How to know which questions to ask on front end for rule based system

Tags: rule-engine, expert-system

I am working on a simple diagnosis rule based expert system. It should ask questions and recognize animal health problems. I am using backward chaining for reasoning. How do i know which questions to ask on front end for asserting new rules? Lets say i have a bunch of rules IF A THEN B, IF B THEN C. Know it will check for C if B is asserted, then it will check if A is asserted. Now since a isn't asserted, i need to ask the question on front end. Is there some methodology for knowing what question to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It largely depends on the details of how the backward chaining is implemented. For example, here's how you can do it in Jess where the engine generates goals that can be matched by rules:

```
Jess> 
(deftemplate symptom
   (declare (backchain-reactive TRUE))
   (slot name)
   (slot value))
TRUE
Jess>    
(deftemplate diagnosis
   (slot name))
TRUE
Jess>    
(deftemplate question
   (slot name)
   (slot string))
TRUE
Jess>    
(deffacts questions
   (question (name has-fever) (string "Does patient have a fever?"))
   (question (name swollen-neck) (string "Does patient have a swollen neck?"))
   (question (name skin-rash) (string "Does patient have a skin rash?")))
TRUE
Jess>    
(defrule measles
   (symptom (name has-fever) (value yes))
   (symptom (name skin-rash) (value yes))
   =>
   (assert (diagnosis (name measles)))
   (printout t "Patient has measles." crlf))
TRUE
Jess> 
(defrule mumps
   (symptom (name has-fever) (value yes))
   (symptom (name swollen-neck) (value yes))
   =>
   (assert (diagnosis (name mumps)))
   (printout t "Patient has mumps." crlf))
TRUE
Jess>    
(defrule ask-question
   (need-symptom (name ?name))
   (question (name ?name) (string ?string))
   (not (diagnosis))
   =>
   (printout t ?string " ")
   (assert (symptom (name ?name) (value (read)))))
TRUE
Jess> (reset)
TRUE
Jess> (run)
Does patient have a fever? yes
Does patient have a swollen neck? yes
Patient has mumps.
3
Jess> (reset)
TRUE
Jess> (run)
Does patient have a fever? yes
Does patient have a swollen neck? no
Does patient have a skin rash? yes
Patient has measles.
4
Jess>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
What will happen if i have subquestions for a certain questions. For example, let's say i want to "Is the patient coughing?" and "Does the patient have a headache?". And then i have subquestion for the coughing, "Does the patient feel pain in lungs when couging?". If a patient answers yes, he is coughing, it should skip the question for headache, and ask the question for feeling pain in lungs. What is the approach for that?

Comment: A detailed explanation of how backward chaining works is too broad to be answered briefly. I would suggest using a search engine with the key words backward chaining algorithm.

Comment: One more questions. The need-symptom is true if there is no fact symptom in the working memory? For example, backward chaining checks the left side of "measles", checks if "has-fever" is asserted, if it isn't it fires the rule to ask question "Does patient have a fever?"

Comment: The need-symptom goals are automatically generated when there is a rule that has an unmatched symptom condition and all prior conditions are satisfied. So initially a (need-symptom (name has-fever) (value yes)) goal is generated as that corresponds to the first unmatched symptom of the measles and mumps rules. When the (symptom (name has-fever) (value yes)) fact is created, then goals are generated for (need-symptom (name skin-rash) (value yes)) and (need-symptom (name swollen-neck) (value yes)).